# How to disable zookeeper debug messages in Spring application?

Tags: spring, maven, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Thanks in advance.

My application uses `Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE` version. It uses the `maven` dependencies for this application. 
The application is also using `Apache Kafka` JAVA API to connect to `Kafka Broker` to send and receive messages.
The application is web based application where we also have the `REST` web services to consume the message from other applications.

PROBLEMS FACING CURRENTLY 
1. `Kafka` uses the `zookeeper` client and it is continuously receiving the ping messages from zookeeper.


**DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: after 242ms.**
I want to disable this message as well as stop ping response from client to `zookeeper` server. It does not allow to start the `Tomcat` server completely.

2. Also how I can disable the DEBUG messages for `Spring` and other applications.

I tried all other methods but does not got any success.

Thanks again in advance.

Avinash Deshmukh

Comment: which other methods - as you mentioned - did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Hi Matteo, I tried to change the log level in 'zookeeper' 'log4j.properties' file. I modified the log level from DEBUG to INFO for 'RollingFileAppender'.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after going detailed debug and going through trial and error basis, I was able to run the code. 

I found that it's all require to identify the proper maven dependency for Kafka and zookeeper.

Below is the required maven dependencies that I have used.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
                <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```